# JavaScript jump function failing, cannot find error

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout

I have the beginnings of a simple game in JavaScript, CSS and HTML and the game was working until I created a jump function. OnClick, the character element (generated by the css as the green rectangle) should jump. Instead, it is static and doesn't move.

Initially, I had this code:

```
.animate{
    animation: jump 500ms;
}
```

in the character's CSS, and it jumped continuously without any user interaction.

What have I done wrong? I assume it is something to do with this:

```
 function jump(){
        character.classList.add("animate");
        setTimeout(function(){
            character.classList.remove("animate");
        },500);
    }
```

For an answer, I would appreciate the error to be pointed out, with new code and a clear explanation as to how the setTimeout function works. Is setTimeout an existing inbuilt method, and if so where do we find documentation on these things?

**CODE**

```js
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var enemy = document.getElementById("enemy");

//adding the animate function in the css here, so it is applied to our character
function jump() {
  character.classList.add("animate");
  setTimeout(function() {
    character.classList.remove("animate");
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 22;
}

#game {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #319b4e;
}

#character {
  width: 30px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 380px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  /*animation: jump 500ms */
}


/* new class called animate */

.animate {
  animation: jump 500ms;
}

#enemy {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: 320px;
  left: 440px;
  animation: moveenemy 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes moveenemy {
  0% {
    left: 440px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 58px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 320x;
  }
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    top: 380px;
  }
  30% {
    top: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 380px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" onclick="jump()">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Game</h1>
  <p>My first ever game</p>
  <p>We all have an enemy</p>


  <div id="game">

    <div id="character"></div>
    <div id="enemy"></div>

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It will be ``getElementById`` not ``getElementbyId``.

Comment: Thank you! Wonder why the editors don't pick this up and flag....solved, thanks

Comment: @Compoot yes I wonder why they closed it, still valid question for setTimeout etc., and its good for beginnres to ask ...

Comment: really appreciate your help - thank you!

Comment: @bluejayke - there's this posted by my colleague (as me) too if you're interested! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048374/javascript-eventlistener-making-a-character-move-right-on-arrow-right-key-press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, after copying the code and testing it, is that the term
`document.getElementById` was spelled with a lowercase `b`, like `document.getElementbyId`, these two lines should instead be:

```
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var enemy = document.getElementById("enemy");`
```

As for `setTimeout`, it is a built in function , that executes a function (provided in first paramter) after a certain amount of time (specified in second parameter), this function works in the background, so it doesn't block other things from happening.

[For more information on setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) (I used this website when I first started learning html etc....)

If you want to change it to the up arrow instead, simply add an `event listener` to check for the keyup event, and check that the keycode matches that for the up arrow (38), and other keys can be checked by `console.log`ing the keyCode for the event, so somewhere in your JavaScript, do

```
addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 38) jump()
})
```

So...

The entire snippet is

```js
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var enemy = document.getElementById("enemy");

//adding the animate function in the css here, so it is applied to our character
function jump(){
    character.classList.add("animate");
    setTimeout(function(){
        character.classList.remove("animate");
    },500);
}

addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 38) jump()
})
```

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:22;
}

#game{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid #319b4e;
}

#character{
    width:30px;
    height:120px;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative;
    top:380px;
    border-radius:20px;
    /*animation: jump 500ms */
    
}

/* new class called animate */
.animate{
    animation: jump 500ms;
}

#enemy{
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:14px;
    position:relative;
    top:320px;
    left:440px;
    animation: moveenemy 1s infinite linear;
    
}

@keyframes moveenemy{
    0%{left:440px;}
    50%{top:58px;}
    100%{left:0px; top:320x;}
}

@keyframes jump{
    0%{top:380px;}
    30%{top:200px;}
    50%{top:200px;}
    100%{top:380px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" onclick="jump()">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Game</h1>
  <p>My first ever game</p>
  <p>We all have an enemy</p>
   
   
   <div id="game">
       
       <div id="character"></div>
       <div id="enemy"></div>
      
   </div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now working

**Issue is**:your write  **document.getElementbyId("character")** but character  **b** of getElementbyid is small so it through error
so correct is **document.getElementById("character")**

```js
    var character = document.getElementById("character");
var enemy = document.getElementById("enemy");

//adding the animate function in the css here, so it is applied to our character
function jump(){
    character.classList.add("animate");
    setTimeout(function(){
        character.classList.remove("animate");
    },500);
}
```

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:22;
}

#game{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid #319b4e;
}

#character{
    width:30px;
    height:120px;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative;
    top:380px;
    border-radius:20px;
    /*animation: jump 500ms */
    
}

/* new class called animate */
.animate{
    animation: jump 500ms;
}

#enemy{
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:14px;
    position:relative;
    top:320px;
    left:440px;
    animation: moveenemy 1s infinite linear;
    
}

@keyframes moveenemy{
    0%{left:440px;}
    50%{top:58px;}
    100%{left:0px; top:320x;}
}

@keyframes jump{
    0%{top:380px;}
    30%{top:200px;}
    50%{top:200px;}
    100%{top:380px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" onclick="jump()">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Game</h1>
  <p>My first ever game</p>
  <p>We all have an enemy</p>
   
   
   <div id="game">
       
       <div id="character"></div>
       <div id="enemy"></div>
      
   </div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is setTimeout an existing inbuilt method, and if so where do we find documentation on these things?

- Yes, `setTimeout` is an inbuilt method. You can learn about more in here [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

> how the setTimeout function works

- So, `setTimeout` method accepts a function/code and a delay (in ms) after which it will execute it. Refer to the above link.

It takes the event into event loop that will make it async call.

I will look into the code after a while and get back to you! :D

Bookmark MDN Web Docs, it is really handy!

Comment: -there's this if you're interested too :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048374/javascript-eventlistener-making-a-character-move-right-on-arrow-right-key-press